# $f$ strictly growing, $f'>0$ and strictly growing $\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$?

Tags: limits, functions, monotone-functions

How can I prove that if $f$ is differential on $(0, \infty)$ and $f'$ is strictly growing on $(0,\infty)$ and, starting at some point $x_0 \in (0,\infty)$, $f'>0$, than $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$?

It makes common sense yet I don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f'(x_0) = M > 0$ and $f'$ is growing then
$$
 f'(x) \ge M \text{ for } x \ge x_0
$$
and therefore, using the mean-value theorem,
$$
 f(x) \ge f(x_0) + (x-x_0)M  \text{ for } x \ge x_0 \, .
$$

You could also argue that $f$ is *convex* and therefore its graph
lies above the tangent line at $x=x_0$, which leads to the same result.

Comment: How does the fact that $f(x) \geq f(x_0) +(x-x_0)M$ imply that $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$? It would imply that if it was true for every $M>0$, but in this case it can't be said for every $M>0$, because there could be a situation where $f'$ has a limit somewhere so that can't be said. Am I missing something?

Comment: @S.Peter: The right-hand side $f(x_0) + (x-x_0)M$ has limit $+\infty$, and the left-hand side  $f(x)$ is $\ge$ the right-hand side. – I did not say that this holds for every $M > 0$. I have chosen a fixed $M = f(x_0) > 0$ which exists according to your question.